# Playing png sequence

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to play a sequence of PNGs in my application using the following code:

```
animatedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Anim_1.png"];
animatedSprite.position = ccp( 512, 435 );
[self animatedSprite z:5];

NSArray *animFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Anim_1.png"],
                       [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"Anim_2.png"], nil];

spriteAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:1.0f/24.0f];

id animAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:spriteAnim];
[spriteAnim runAction:animAction];
```

the 'animatedSprite' is added correctly but the animation doesn't play. What am I missing here?

I am using Cocos2d 2.0, xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

You should run the action on the sprite, not the animation.

```
[animatedSprite runAction:animAction];
```

Comment: The above answer is probably correct .. also make sure to add the sprite properly: [self addChild:animatedSprite z:5] on the 3rd line (might just be a typo)

Comment: Yes, it was jus a typo. I fixed it and modified the 'runAction' line but nothing seems to work!